# Absolute path in the tsconfig doesn't work

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I saw some questions about [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171944/typescript-how-to-resolve-absolute-modules-paths-for-node-js), none of them does not work
I have a nodejs project along with Typescript. I do not like to use a relative path.I get the following error, when I set path in tsconfig :

> Cannot find module '@app/controllers/main'

```
// main.ts
export const fullName = "xxxx";
...

// app.ts
import { fullName } from '@app/controllers/main'
...
```

This is the structure of my project :

```
-node_modules
-src
----controllers
---------------main.ts
----app.ts
-package.json
-tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": ["src/*"]
        },
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
}
```

Where is my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you receive the error? As you built your code or TSC complier showing on IDE?

Comment: When I want to run the project with this command : ``ts-node-dev src/index.ts``

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use pure `tsc` instead?

Answer (score 19):

## Update 2023

1. Install development dependencies

```bash
npm install --save-dev \
  ts-patch \
  typescript-transform-paths \ 
  tsconfig-paths
```

- [`ts-patch`](https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch) 
  Directly patch typescript installation to allow custom transformers (plugins). 
  The main difference why I prefer `ts-patch` over `ttypescript` is that there is no need to change the compiler (`ttsc`) because (hence the name) `tsc` is patched.
- [`typescript-transform-paths`](https://github.com/LeDDGroup/typescript-transform-paths) 
  Transforms absolute imports to relative from paths in your `tsconfig.json`.
- [`tsconfig-paths`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) 
  Load modules whose location is specified in the paths section of `tsconfig.json`. Both loading at run-time and via API are supported.

2. Update `tsconfig.json`

> **Note**: See [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) and [`plugins`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#plugins)

```json
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the baseUrl */
      "paths":{
         "~/*":[
            "./src/*"
         ]
      },
      /* List of language service plugins */
      "plugins":[
         /* Transform paths in output .js files */
         {
            "transform":"typescript-transform-paths"
         },
         /* Transform paths in output .d.ts files */
         {
            "transform":"typescript-transform-paths",
            "afterDeclarations": true
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

3. Patch `Typescript`

> **Note**: This is **NOT persistent**

```bash
npx ts-patch install
```

4. Edit/Add [`prepare script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/using-npm/scripts#prepare-and-prepublish) in `package.json` to patch `Typescript` persistently

> **Note**: This **IS persistent**

```json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npx ts-patch install -s"
  }
}
```

5. Usage in `import`

```
import { hello } from '~/world';
```

6. Compile as always

```bash
npx tsc
```

## Old Answer

Unfortunately (and I don't know why) the Typescript compiler currently does not support the paths transformation very well.

Here is my solution:

I used the solution with [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server) project.

## Install devDependencies

1. **[ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript)** -> *npm install ttypescript --save-dev* -> TTypescript (Transformer TypeScript) solves the problem by patching on the fly the compile module to use transformers from tsconfig.json.
2. **[typescript-transform-paths](https://github.com/LeDDGroup/typescript-transform-paths)** -> *npm install typescript-transform-paths --save-dev* -> Transforms absolute imports to relative from paths in your tsconfig.json.
3. **[tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths)** -> *npm install tsconfig-paths --save-dev* -> Use this to load modules whose location is specified in the paths section of tsconfig.json. Both loading at run-time and via API are supported.
4. **[ts-node-dev](https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev)** -> *npm install ts-node-dev --save-dev* -> It restarts target node process when any of required files changes (as standard node-dev) but shares Typescript compilation process between restarts

## tsconfig.json

Update the *tsconfig.json* file with the following options:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ]
        },
        /* Advanced Options */
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "typescript-transform-paths"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

## Build

For the compilation phase use *ttsc* instead of *tsc* with the configuration file. See the snippet below:

```bash
npx ttsc --p ./tsconfig.json
```

## Development mode with autoreload

When you are in dev mode use the following script (put it in the scripts options in package.json) to automatically reload the project with the correct paths. The *src/app.ts* is the "entry point" of your application located under the *src* folder.

```bash
npx ts-node-dev --prefer-ts true --no-notify -r tsconfig-paths/register --watch src --transpileOnly src/app.ts
```

PS: Using ts-node-dev increase the speed significantly.

Comment: The reason why is that paths was never intended to transform module specifiers in the output. Rather, it is meant to _describe_ such transformations, as performed by other tools to the language for typechecking purposes. Poster child use cases for paths include RequireJS `config.paths`, SystemJS `config.{packages|paths|map}`, and Webpack `module.resolve.{alias|modules}`. Furthermore, TypeScript avoids rewriting module specifiers in the output for a _**whole host**_ of reasons

Comment: compilerOptions + plugins finally arrived ??!!!!! how long did we wait for that. cool. great answer although i wished there would be a simple solution to sometimes wanted absolute paths ;)

Comment: When I try to run my code with `node dist/app.js` I'm getting this error: `Error: Cannot find module`

Comment: @NikhilWagh can you add more information. Thanks

Comment: The absolute import statements are not properly transformed into relative import statements in the compiled javascript, hence I'm getting `Cannot find module` for the modules I have written in the app.

Comment: @NikhilWagh Strange... Can you share the code? Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I tweak @Carlo Corradini answer a little bit,
here is my approach to fix this issue.

1. install required plugins:
   `npm i -D ttypescript typescript-transform-paths ts-node tsconfig-paths`. these are packages that will help us to transform the paths.

    ttypescript-> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript
2. then, on tsconfig.json, I put:

   ```
   {

    "ts-node": {
      "transpileOnly": true,
      "require": [  // set this so you dont need to use ts-node -r 
        "typescript-transform-paths/register",
        "tsconfig-paths/register"
       ]
    },         
    "compilerOptions": {
       "composite": true,
       "rootDir": ".", // must define
       "baseUrl": "src", // must define, the paths will relative to this
       "outDir": "lib", 
       "skipLibCheck": false,
       "paths": {
        "@app/*": ["./*"],
        "@controllers/*": ["./controllers/*"],
       },
        "plugins": [
          { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" }
        ]
    }
   }
   ```
3. then on your codes you can use:

   ```
   import myControllers from "@controllers/main.ts"
   ```
4. now you can compile, `npx ttsc -p tsconfig.json`
5. and to run on ts-node use `npx ts-node -p tsconfig.json src/app.ts`

Answer (score 6):

## Update (as of March 2023)

The previous answers were helpful for development but I was still facing issues in production when I would run my build file.

The way I solved it **once and for all** is by using the [`tsc-alias`](https://github.com/justkey007/tsc-alias#readme) package in build and the [`tsconfig-paths`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths#readme) in development.

### Setup instructions:

1. Install `tsc-alias` & `tsconfig-paths` as a dev dependency with:

```
npm i -D tsc-alias tsconfig-paths
```

2. Use `tsconfig-paths` in your dev or start script like so:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts", // here I am using ts-node-dev
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts" // works with node too, see tsconfig-paths doc
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

3. Append `tsc-alias` in the build script.
   In your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

And that's it. You are done. You can now use both path alias **AND** absolute imports and build your app without running into `module not found` issues.

Here's my `tsconfig.json` for reference:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "src", // notice my base url is set to ./src folder
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "paths": {
      "@middlewares": ["_globals/middlewares"], // referring to ./src/_globals/middlewares folder 
      "@exceptions": ["_globals/exceptions"],
      "@utils": ["_globals/utils"]
    }
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ], // if you need absolute path or path alias outside src then include the directory accordingly
  "exclude": ["src/test.ts"] // import won't work in this file/directory
}
```

### Usage

You can now use both absolute import and path alias:

```
import { sth } from "_globals/sth"; // using absolute imports
import { sth } from "@utils"; // using path alias
```

Your build file should also run without any `module not found` errors.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is correct.

It appears that, at the time of writing, `ts-node-dev` does not support the `paths` entry of `tsconfig.json`.

This [github issue](https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev/issues/95) discusses the problem and presents workaround options.