# NodeJS Typescript: Cannot resolve root path

Tags: node.js, typescript

I cannot import module from root path, example:

```
import { encryptPassword, generateLoginToken } from "src/helpers/crypto";
```

here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
  }
}
```

I am using `VS Code`. It is fine, the VS Code does not complain about the path, but after I run:

```
nodemon ./src/app.ts
```

There is error saying the module is not found:

> Error: Cannot find module 'src/entity/owner'

If I use relative path:

```
import { encryptPassword, generateLoginToken } from "../helpers/crypto";
```

Then it works. I do not want to use relative path. How can I fix this?

Comment: `"rootDir"` should never appear in import paths and `"baseUrl"` is relative it. The correct code would be `import { encryptPassword, generateLoginToken } from "helpers/crypto";`

Comment: The module is at `src/helpers/crypto`, how can I configure this?

Comment: That's what `"rootDir"` does

Comment: Don’t you want to change the absolute import starting with source? The advise above is quite helpful if src is your main dir and you only need to change your import path by removing src

Comment: @AlvinStefanus maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63745316/6676781) could be useful for your needs :)